# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec... when trying to encode a structure for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I'm trying to create a unicode string out of a python structure. I don't want to use python's default string conversion methods since I want this unicode string to be in a particular structure so that I can use it in the javascript client. I get the UnicodeDecodeError at line

```
dlist_str += unicode(item[key])
```

I've tried

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of the file. I've also tried the problem line with

```
dlist_str += item[key]
```

hoping the str type will auto-covert to unicode. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

---

```
def convertToString(dlist):
  dlist_str = u'{ '
  for item in dlist:
    dlist_str += item['field_id'] + u': { '
    for key in item:
      dlist_str +=  key + u': '
      dt = str(type(item[key]))
      if dt == "<type 'str'>" or dt == "<type 'unicode'>":
        dlist_str += u"'"
        dlist_str += unicode(item[key])
        dlist_str += u"'"
      elif dt == "<type 'list'>":
        dlist_str += u"["
        for dn in item[key]:
          dlist_str += u"'" + dn + u"',"
        dlist_str += u"]"
      else:
        dlist_str += unicode(item[key])
      dlist_str += u','
    dlist_str += u'},'
  dlist_str += u'}'
  return dlist_str
```

---

Comment: `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` is used to allow your code to be read by vim/emacs considering `utf-8` encoding -- only. Please post the exact output, and the call to the function `convertToString`, so we can mace yer problem good. (simpsons)

Comment: @Rubens: not true. The particular formatting of `-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` is a hint for emacs (Vim would use a modeline, e.g. `vim: fileencoding=utf-8`), but Python *does* use the `coding: utf-8` part to indicate that the file is UTF-8 rather than ASCII; if you put a Unicode character not in the ASCII range inside the file, e.g. `λ`, it will cause a `SyntaxError` if you don't have `coding: utf-8`, but will work correctly if you do. See [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). But remember that that is just the *source* encoding.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Yep, there's this little variation between vim/emacs, but adding such a thing in the script concerns the code only, not the data being treated by the code.

Comment: `str(type(x)) == "<type 'str'>"`? Please don't. Use `type(x) == str` (exact type match) or `isinstance(x, str)` (subclasses permitted). To cover `str` and `unicode` at one stroke, you would have `isinstance(x, basestring)`.

Comment: @Rubens: my point is simply that it does affect Python's behaviour too, though not in the way hoped for.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan oui, but it has to do with the code reading/interpretation only; it does not affect whether an input file read will be treated as unicode.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, Thanks for the isinstance suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do two things at once: convert the list to a dictionary, and JSON encode it.

If you separate the two steps, you should be able to use the [JSON Encoder in the Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

def convertToString(dlist):
    temp_dict = dict((item['field_id'], item) for item in dlist)
    return json.dumps(temp_dict)
    # or, even shorter, and in Python 2.7/3.2+
    # return json.dumps({item['field_id']: item for item in dlist})
```

Separately, the reason you're seeing the error in your version is that you need to explicitly select a "from" encoding rather than letting Python guess. Something like:

```
dlist_str += item[key].decode('utf-8')
```

would probably work.

Comment: Your json.dumps solution is very elegant. Thanks.